# Writing real-time output to a window or text pane during MSTEST

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I'm using the [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) facility to do logging, and I'd like the log output to appear in a window or text pane somewhere in Visual Studio *during the test.*

What is the simplest way to achieve this?  `Debug.Print()` statements only show up at the end of the test.  Trying to open a console window seems like a non-starter (it's not a console application, and I can't seem to get the correct handle).

I'm using my own static Log class, so I don't have to use Trace to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()
```

will be captured by the Visual Studio Output Window if you run in Debug mode and this should not depend on test execution stage (start/end of a test), so it should be tracked in debug output as soon as executed.

Such kind of output also could be captured and filtered by tools like [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647)

EDIT: answer to comment

I've created MSTest test and able to observe in Debug Window how each new line comes up per each second: (In the output window you can choose between `Build/Debug`, please ensure you've selected `Debug` option in drop down list)

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    int i = 10;

    while(i-- > 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Debug.WriteLine("Step #" + i);
    }
}
```

The test must be run from the **Test\Debug\Tests In Current Context** menu.  The Run Tests option from the right-click context menu *will not work.*

Comment: Yes, but not in real-time, as far as I can tell.  I only get the output when the test is completed.

Comment: You're calling it the `Debug Window.` What is its *exact name,* and where in the VS menu can I find it?

Comment: Visual Studio Menu: View -> Output -> Select option "Show output from Debug"

Comment: Yeah, nada.  Test project is set to Debug.  All the writelines are appearing in the Test Results Debug trace, but zippo in the Output/Debug window.

Comment: There it goes. Looks like you have to actually `Test/Debug/Tests in Current Context`; you can't just `Right Click/Run Tests`.

Comment: Looks like you've solved this issue but unfortunately I don't got what you are mean about Test.Debug/Tests in Current Context, really interesting what happens there